# Copiar datos de un campo form a otro campo del mismo form Laravel

Tags: html, laravel-5

Quisiera copiar los datos de un campo a otro en el mismo formulario, al momento, sin tener que hacer otra acción. Algo parecido a un keylogger y lo que escriba en un campo se vaya insertando en otro campo al mismo tiempo. Se puede? gracias

```
<form action="procesar" method="POST">
    <div class="col1">
      <input type="text" name="content" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col1">
      <input type="text" name="content1" required>
    </div>
</form>
```

Para que cuando se haya terminado de escribir en el campo `content` se tenga el mismo contenido en el campo `content1` al mismo tiempo

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es crear un codigo JavaScript o Jquery que escuche el evento del campo y lo reproduzca en el otro campo

Comment: Podrías explicarme un poco más? Soy nuevo en el desarrollo web, gracias

Comment: ok te hago la explicacion

Comment: Te lo agradezco mucho :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te lo han comentado, esto es mediante javascript o lo puedes lograr también con jquery, jquery es una librería que ofrece las mismas funcionalidades que javascript pero es más amigable.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como puedes lograrlo: https://jsfiddle.net/L9atcrk0/

Desde este link puedes descargar/utilizar la librería de jquery: https://code.jquery.com/

Además desde aquí puedes ver algunos eventos que se utilizan en algunos elementos html relacionados al teclear: https://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

Te recomiendo hacer la mayoría de búsquedas en ingles, así encontrarás más información.

Te incluyo el código en caso que desaparezca de la página:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input[name=content]").keyup(function(){
   $("input[name=content1]").val(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCtype>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  <form action="procesar" method="POST">
    <div class="col1">
      <input type="text" name="content" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col1">
      <input type="text" name="content1" required>
    </div>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El código de jquery en dónde se debe de poner? Una disculpa, soy nuevo en esto :) Gracias

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias por el aporte. en cuanto al codigo Jquery lo colocas debajo del <script> que llama a la libreria, en otro bloque <script>

Comment: Aún no puedo hacer funcionar la solución, creen que se deba a `{{csrf_field()}}`?

Comment: Tengo mi etiqueta `<head>` con el script que viene en el link que escribió Ernesto y debajo de esa última, en otra etiqueta de script, tengo el primer bloque de código que escribió. Estoy haciéndolo bien? @AlexanderRodriguez

Comment: Tambien te puede servir, lo importante es que siempre declares primero la libreria JQuery y despues puedes usar el codigo

Comment: Ya quedó, fue un error mío. En el head tengo un script con lo que venía en el link de uso de JQuery y debajo otro script con lo que viene en el primer bloque de código de la respuesta. Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias